# Initialising 2d dynamic Array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to C and trying to initialise a 2D array. I need both columns of the array to be char *, as they will contain string values.

I have it working with the array storing ints but for some reason, when I try to store string values when it prints it displays `(null)`. Below is the code for how I am initialising and storing the data as an int (This appears to be working).

```
int **array;
    int row = 0;

    array = malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    }

    array[0][0] = i;
    array[0][1] = i;

    printf("array[0][0]: %i\n", array[0][0]);
```

Below is how I am doing the above but using string values instead.

```
char **array;
int row = 0;

array = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    array[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
}

array[0][0] = "Test[0][0]";
array[0][1] = "Test[0][1]";

printf("array[0][0]: %s\n", array[0][0]);
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033315/correct-way-to-allocate-and-free-arrays-of-pointers-to-arrays/17033507#17033507) and make your life much easier

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up two different concepts, pointer to pointer and 2D array. These are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong level of pointer indirection, which is over-complicating things.

I think it would be easier for you if you thought of the array as an array of structures, each structure holding two pointers:

```
struct row {
  char *column1;
  char *column2;
};
```

then it's (hopefully) clearer that once you've allocated an array of `struct row`, you *have* two pointers in each row, you don't need to allocate room for the pointers themselves.

```
const size_t num_rows = 1;
struct row * rows = malloc(num_rows * sizeof *rows);
if(rows != NULL)
{
  rows[0].column1 = "row 0, column 1";
  rows[0].column2 = "row 1, column 2";
}
```

Note that this uses string literals, otherwise you might need to allocate room for the strings to be stored, depending on where the data comes from.

The `num_rows` value could of course come from anywhere in your program, I'm just trying to illustrate what controls the number of rows memory is allocated for.

Comment: Thanks this seemed to work. The only thing I don't get is what is 1 * sizeof, is the 1 referring to the number of rows that it should contain. So if I had to store 50 rows, would it be ``malloc(50 * sizeof *rows)``

Comment: @Boardy Yes exactly. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself the trouble and don't use 2D arrays in C.  It's more convenient to use 1D arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    const int nstrings = 2;
    const int width = 20; //width of maximum string.

    char* array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*nstrings*width);
    strcpy(&array[0*width],"Test[0][0]");
    strcpy(&array[1*width],"Test[1][0]");
    printf("string 0: %s\n", &array[0*width]); 
    printf("string 1: %s\n", &array[1*width]);
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). And don't use `sizeof (char)`, it adds nothing but clutter. Also, that's pretty ... complicated code, and very different from what the question wanted.

Comment: Those are quite pedantic comments.  The cast is necessary for it to compile in MSVC as well as C++ (your firm believe in them being separate languages does not have to be my believe).  `Sizeof` helps clarify how to do this with other datatypes larger than char.  Why break the symmetry for char only (I don't need to write `0*width` either but I think it makes it more clear)?  Personally, I think 2D arrays are more complicated so from my point of view my code is less complicated.